# "Not Enough Local Storage": How much local storage is needed for iCloud Photos with "Optimize Mac Storage" on?

Tags: icloud, photos, storage

Photos on macOS has a preference under iCloud Photos called "Optimize Mac Storage" that results in the replacement of full-resolution photos/videos by thumbnails/low-resolution photos to preserve local storage.

I have created a separate 75 GB APFS Volume on my 1 TB disk [to keep the photo library size under control](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/371174/strictly-limit-macos-photos-library-size-using-optimize-storage). This has worked well generally, but lately I've gotten an error saying the library can't sync because there's not enough local storage.

[image: Not Enough Local Storage]

> Syncing Paused for X Items - Settings
> Not Enough Local Storage

I imagine there's a minimum fraction of the total library size that's needed locally to store thumbnails/low-resolution version of the photos, but in typical Apple fashion, this information is not available anywhere that I know of. So the question is:

How much local storage is needed for iCloud Photo with "Optimize Mac Storage" on?

Comment: This link claims a 90% storage savings. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7855665

I don't know if that is true, but I would guess that the actual amount of space is variable based on the number of photos and how often you scroll through them, thinking that it probably needs a certain amount for a thumbnail and meta data for each photo. So there may not be a hard number to go with.

Comment: Hi @StephenCollins, yeah, I saw that post when researching this question, but seems largely a guess.

Comment: How much storage are you aleady using out of the 1TB?

Comment: Good relevant presales question in the age of MacBook Pros with Apple Silicon being a System on a Chip with RAM and SSD size being fixed and not-upgradeable. 

I also wonder if my Library currently has around 500 GB, how much the optimized version can be shrinked down to, in order to know how much headroom to have on the SSD. Is the local optimized version taking 10%, 20%, 50% of the originals in iCloud? Knowing the rough factor would help.

Or more concretely: How much reduction rate per photos? Per videos? Per codec? Then I could get a realistic estimate.